# Displaying proper time on Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement full calendar on a Heroku app. I have to display  all my events in this calendar. The issue I am facing is that the time being displayed is not proper. For example I am having a record with date time value as `Sun, 08 Oct 2017 10:00:00` but instead of 10 am it shows 10pm in calendar.

Comment: Time is correct in your local app ?

Comment: time value in your database is UTC time. You need to set a time zone in your `application.rb` so that app can dislay correct time based on your time zone setting.

Comment: @Vishal thanks for the response. Yes the time is correct in my local app.

Comment: However Thanks to @Thanh, his solution worked for me. :) Thank you guys.

Comment: @Vishal I think this question may popular and make an answer for it, please mark it as accepted if it worked.

Comment: @Thanh answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime value which is stored in database is UTC time.

You need to set a time zone in `application.rb` file so that app can show correct time based on time zone setting.